# Php operators and destruct func

Tags: php

```
function _destruct()  
{if(!this->needsupdate)   
  return;  

 $sql='update widget set';  
 $sql.="name =".mysql_real_escape_string($this->name)."',";  
 $sql.="description=".mysql_real_escape_string($this->description)."'";  
 $sql.="where widgetid=".this->id;  

 $rs=mysql_query($query,$this->connect);  
 if(!is_resource($rs))  
 throw new exception("an error occured updating the database");  

 mysql_close;  
 }
```

Can anyone please tell me what is happening in the `$sql=`... statements... Means I can't understand the function of dots here...

Please explain in detail. Widget is a table in mysql having widgetid, name, description as columns.

Answer (score 1):

The "dot" performs [***string concatenation*** <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Example from the documentation:

```
<?php
$a = "Hello ";
$b = $a . "World!"; // now $b contains "Hello World!"

$a = "Hello ";
$a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Append to string.

```
$x = "a";
$x .= "b";
echo $x; // "ab"
```

Your $sql...

```
update widget set name = something', description = something' where widgetid = 1;
```

Should be:

```
UPDATE widget SET name = 'something', description = 'something' WHERE widgetid = 1
```

Comment: SQL keywords don't have to be upper case.

Comment: Do you write keywords in uppercase?

Comment: It does not matter what I do. But I see now that you actually meant the missing quotes, I suppose. You should write  this explicitly to not create misunderstandings ;) (like in my case :o))

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant by "should be" ;) Uppercase, lowercase, doesn't matter, but I prefer uppercase.